# How to convert a downloaded NSData type to a video type to be played on iPhone Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiimageview, nsdata

I am downloading a `NSData` file from a chat server, and I know that this file is uploaded normally as a video file. I would like to get this file and display it as a video Safari. I think that in order to do that I cannot display it as an `NSData`, is that right? if not, what is the format that I can have this file in in order to display it in my iPhone?

so I started to think about converting it back again to a video file, and here is what I used based on [this answer: How to convert video data to NSURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145262/how-to-convert-video-data-to-nsurl)

The answer explains that we can convert the video to a `URL` to use it to play the video later. I have tried the solution and got the `URL`. However the url of type string that I get could not be played on Safari so I assumed I might be doing something wrong. I am supposing that the error might come from the way I use encoding, as I am not sure about what to put in it.

Please note that `filePath` is the one containing the path to the `NSData` file.

```
            let filePath = self.documentsPathForFileName(name: "video.mov")


            do { try [videomessage?.url.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)]}
            catch{
                print ("error")
            }
            let videoFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

            print (videoFileURL)

func documentsPathForFileName(name: String) -> String {

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    return documentsPath + name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have the video in the form of `Data`. So, it needs to be saved first and converted. Try this:

```
[/*name of NSData*/ writeToFile:/*save file path*/ atomically: YES];
NSURL *filepath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:/*save file path*/];
AVPlayerItem *player = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:filepath];
```

Untested, but should work.

If you already have the `URL` then you can directly play the video:

```
func playVideo() {

       // setup video player
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player

        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }

       //  setup autorotate to landscape orientation
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }
```